# Chances for a specific party member to be targeted out of n party members?

Tags: final-fantasy

In Final Fantasy 1, the chance for a given party member, in the party of four, to be targeted by a single-target attack depends on their placement order as follows:

1. 50% chance, 1 in 2
2. 25% chance, 1 in 4
3. 12.5% chance, 1 in 8
4. 12.5% chance, 1 in 8

But how does having less living and unpetrified (call them "targetable" for simplicity) party members change the odds? Obviously, having only one targetable party member will get them targeted 100% of the time, but what about two or three targetable party members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target of a monster in Final Fantasy is determined by generating a random number. According to the [source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/nes/522595-final-fantasy/faqs/57009#Targeting) I found:

> If an enemy's action is single-target in nature (regular attack or
> appropriate Spell/Skill), the enemy generates a random number, R =
> 1...8. This number determines that enemy's target:
>
> Slot 1: 1-4 (50% Chance)
>
> Slot 2: 5-6 (25% Chance)
>
> Slot 3: 7 (12.5% Chance)
>
> Slot 4: 8 (12.5% Chance)
>
> If the target chosen is Dead or Petrified, it generates a new random
> number  until a valid target is selected.

Extrapolating from that, if the first party member is dead, the second has a 50% chance of being attacked and the other two have a 25% chance. If both the first and second party members die then the remaining party members have a 50% chance if being attacked. And so on.